# Ansible collection - reusing the role from github

Tags: github, collections, ansible, roles

I have a repository with two roles in Github. My team needs to reuse the roles in another repository along with one more role. I do not want to download and update the role as my role in Githubcan get updated so we need to use it from Github only.

[image]

Comment: Does this solve your problem: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html?

Comment: Create a collection with the 3 roles in one single repo and remove those two repos. Now you only have a single collection to download.

Comment: it s aproject worked by multiple teammates. i will need to use it from git and reuse it. if another person does changes in repository the changes will not be refelcted in mine when i download and uplad the roles

Comment: And how does my above proposition makes your requirement impossible ?

Comment: it doesnt make it impossible.it doesnt serve my purpose when we have n number of roles in n number of repository.  i need to reuse the roles from multiple repository.

Comment: so the answer I think is that this is not possible when using Ansible. The idea of collections is reuse but this reuse does not include roles and / or tasks.